# Creating web workers dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-worker

I would like to be able to create web workers dynamically in a foreach loop. I am not sure if I am doing this correctly but here is what I am attempting.

main.js:

```
$('#action-options').on('click', '#act_restart', function() {

    $.each(checked, function(key, val) {
        var worker = new Worker('js/doWork.js');
        worker.addEventListener('message', onMsg, false);
        worker.addEventListener('error', onError, false);
        worker.postMessage({'inst': val});

    });

});
```

doWork.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
var data = e.data;
var xmlhttp;
var tableData;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        tableData = xmlhttp.responseText;
        self.postMessage(tableData);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "../apicall/"+data.inst, true);
xmlhttp.send();

}, false);
```

I would like to fire a worker for each AJAX call so that if one takes longer than another it will not hold up the page. or any of the others.

How is this possible with web workers?

Comment: You'll have to create the workers inside the loop with local variables, the same goes for the event handlers, otherwise you really just have one single worker.

Comment: @adeneo I edited my question for my new code, I am still having trouble. i have added a sleep() in my backed api function if the data matches a certain string. this works the first time but any subsequent requests will sleep for all items in the loop.

Comment: Given that AJAX requests are asynchronous anyway, why do you need web workers to handle them? You could do this just by creating a set of AJAX calls with callbacks.